# combine history across tty

Tags: linux, bash

At any given time I have 3 logins to the same server.  Sure, I often use screen, but assume this purpose allows me to have:

```
 1 session running something
 1 session looking at output
 1 session shuffling files to/from various places
```

If at any point I lose all three connections, I lose 2/3 of my history, as when I log back in, I get the history from a random 1 of my three connections.

Is there a way to stop this and combine all three history files into 1?

Alternatively, is there a way to declare each login as "ttyN" thus keeping each with its separate history separate, but retrievable / re-connectable?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you need your history for?  A solution to your issue seems non-trivial to do from scratch...

Comment: You can define the name of the history file a bash has to use. The file is writtten on exit of the bash process. (But i never made use of it.) Using this, you could have 3 different history files as long as you start your bash with different settings of 'HISTFILE'

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution?

After you have opened your Terminal /Screen

start your shell with a History-File setting:

```
HISTFILE=$HOME/session1-history  bash
```

and continue to work with this bash.
 To run a different session history

```
HISTFILE=$HOME/session2-history  bash
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this in your `.bashrc` file.

```
# Avoid duplicates..
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups  

# Append history entries..
shopt -s histappend    

# After each command, save and reload history
export PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND$'\n'}history -a; history -c; history -r"
```

Found this answer at this [Unix Stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1292).

I tried this and it seems to work on multiple terminals simultaneously, only catch is you've to execute a command for the terminal to fetch the latest history from .bash_history.

So for example, if I open the first terminal and type `echo check 1` and then open a second terminal and type `echo check 2`. Now if I go back to the first terminal and press the up key, I won't get `echo check 2`, since the last time the history was fetched from the history file was when I executed the previous command. So I can just press `Enter` without specifying a command and it will fetch the last history entries. Now if I press the up key, it will show up `echo check 2`, which is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source shell history logger for bash and zsh which would solve your problem (disclaimer: I wrote and maintain it).

https://github.com/barabo/advanced-shell-history

The idea is that your commands are written into a sqlite3 database using a builtin bash hook.  If you really needed to go back and figure out what commands you entered / how long they ran / what their exit codes were - you should give it a try.

It's saved me many times.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous options you can set to prevent Bash instances from overwriting each others history. See [this FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/088) for a full explanation:

In your `.bashrc`, add

```
HISTFILESIZE=400000000
HISTSIZE=10000
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"
export HISTSIZE PROMPT_COMMAND
shopt -s histappend
```

Comment: Does not appear to work.  I inserted this into .bashrc, rebooted (needed to do so anyway), and on re-login, tty commands from session 2 are not in history of session 1.  Nor vice versa.

Comment: This only prevents different shells from overwriting the history file. It does not make history from one running shell available in another one in real time. If you close both shells in arbitrary order and start a third one, you'll see that history from both are available in the third, as opposed to only one before you started.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your requirements right you have multiple terminal sessions open and want commands entered in one session to be available via history in other sessions.

You need to put these lines on top of your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export HISTFILESIZE=100000
export HISTSIZE=100000
# avoid & erase dups
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
shopt -s histappend
# save & reload history after each command enter in shell
export PROMPT_COMMAND="\history -a; \history -c; \history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Most important is `histappend` which makes sure that new history lines are appended to the history file each time.

PS: You need to press enter to see most recently added history in each session.

For more robust solution see: http://ptspts.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-automatically-synchronize-shell.html